# Colocar menu na margem inferior do navbar Bootstrap 3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Tenho o seguinte menu:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ele ficou desse tamanho porque o cliente exigiu que a logo ficasse maior, porém o menu ficou no topo da navbar. Como faço para que ela fique na base inferior da navbar?

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" style="background: #00253f; height: 110px">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="images/logo.png" style="width: 150px"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Início</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Quem Somos</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Serviços</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Galeria</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contato</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para retirar os cantos redondos:

```
.navbar{
   border-radius: 0;
}
```

Posicionar o menu no canto inferior direito:

```
#myNavbar{
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 0;
   right: 0;
}
```

**Exemplo (execute em tela cheia):**

```css
.navbar{
   border-radius: 0;
}

#myNavbar{
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 0;
   right: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" style="background: #00253f; height: 110px">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="images/logo.png" style="width: 150px"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right navbar-bottom">
        <li><a href="#">Início</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Quem Somos</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Serviços</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Galeria</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contato</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Show de bola Sam. Muito obrigado mais uma vez!